# Android Fragment: the specified child already has a parent fragment - Error

Tags: android, layout, view, parent, fragment

i´m stock on a Problem with Androids Fragments.

I have a Fragment-Activity which consits of a TabHost with 4 Tabs.
One of these Tabs shows a diagramm. The calculation of the data for the diagram is complex and takes a while. 
The Problem: Let us assume the User clicks on the specific Tab, the computing of the diagramm starts and everything works fine. Now the user clicks on the next tab, and the app shows the content. After that the User switches back to the Diagramm-Tab. So it does not reload, i do the following in the onCreateView of the Diagramm-Fragment:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(layout == null){
        layout = new PedelecRelativeLayout(getActivity());
        initUI();
    }
    return layout;
}
```

As you can see, if the layout is null, it will be initiate and the initUI() generates the Diagramm.

The first click of the tab works, but on the second click on the tab, the app is crashing with the following Error:

```
11-20 10:32:36.928: E/AndroidRuntime(9888): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 10:32:36.928: E/AndroidRuntime(9888): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The     specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Heres a Code-Snipplet of my Fragment-Activity with the Tab-Host:

```
summaryDiagram = (SummaryDiagramFragment)  fm.findFragmentByTag(TAB_DIAGRAM);
...
if(summaryDiagram != null){
                ft.detach(summaryDiagram);
            }
...

if(tabId.equals(TAB_DIAGRAM)){
                if(summaryDiagram==null){
                    /** Create AndroidFragment and adding to fragmenttransaction */
                    summaryDiagram = new SummaryDiagramFragment();
                    ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, summaryDiagram, TAB_DIAGRAM);
                }else{
                    /** Bring to the front, if already exists in the fragmenttransaction */
                    ft.attach(summaryDiagram);
                }
            }
```

Thanks for your help, and my sry for my bad english :-)

Answer (score 0):

You must not detach and then re-attach fragment by yourself. It should remain on activity.
To obtain the fragment instance after each onCreate(Bundle arg) call you must find your fragment in the FragmentManager if activity is restoring from saved state.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

    } else {
        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, YourFragment.class.getName());
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, YourFragment.class.getName());
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```